# How to "extract interface from a class" in TypeScript using VSCode?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, refactoring

For example, in C# and Visual Studio, you can right click on class, and click on an option to extract an interface from a class, which will basically auto-generate all the public methods/properties signatures as an interface. This feature is a pretty handy refactoring when you're trying to make code unit-testable.

Is there a way to do the above using TypeScript and VSCode? It doesn't look like this feature is supported out of the box.

Comment: You can create a pull-request for the C# extension of VSC

Answer (score 2):

Afaik there is no such thing: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-refactoring

But you could create an extension that parses AST and runs through public functions and creates an interface.

Comment: why build an AST when the C# extension already has one

Comment: The question was about Typescript and VSCcode and not Visual Studio and C#. I said "parses AST", not build one.